# what limitations stop a person from installing solar panels on his/her house?

Tags: energy, solar-cells

Solar energy is a great form of energy. sourced from the sun, it can save a great deal of electricity bill cost. My question is why doesn't everyone uses it and install panels on their roof.

Of course, sun rays is the most significant factor of all but what other limitations are there to it? Cost of panels, less availability, not efficient, less generation of electricity are few I could think of. But, I'm not sure about any of them.

Since limitations can be many in number and can belong to different nodes of stack exchange network. The question was little related to energy, so I decided to ask it here. If this is not the right platform then do tell.

Comment: Capital cost, recovery of cost on moving, local/state/federal subsidies, direction of sloped roof, trees - all these are engineering or policy or financial decisions, not physics questions.

Comment: This is rather a question about economy. It doesn't matter that this is about energy - if you could save a grea tdeal of your milk bill by installing a cow on your roof, the decision process would be similar

Comment: There also might be legal reasons, for example if a homeowner's association or a local power company prohibits their installation.

Comment: Upon analyzing all the reasons mentioned in the comments, marking the question by one label wouldn't have served the purpose. Don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that not everyone has solar panels is that they are not economical.

Simply put, investing X dollars in bonds will usually generate a greater financial return than putting the same X dollars into solar panels.  This is because the price of a solar panel is larger than the value of the electricity it will produce during its lifetime.

However, in very sunny climates - and when the government will help pay for the panels - they can be made economical from the point of view of a consumer.  Usually, though, governments will subsidize solar panels only to the point where they are almost, but not quite, a good return on investment.

To the extent that solar panels are actually economically efficient utility companies do employ them - and in a much more cost-efficient way than having individual homeowners install and maintain small-scale systems.